# Should I add my blog posts as regular HTML pages on my website

Tags: seo, blog

I have a main website (`http://www.example.com`) and a blog (`http://blog.example.com`), the blog is powered by Blogger. Sometimes users may do a search and it brings up the blog page but I think it would be useful if the search took the users directly to my website. Would it be a good idea to replicate my blog articles as HTML pages.

Comment: Technically, a blog subdomain already is part of your website, even if it is hosted by some other company.   How would it be more useful to users to land on the same content, but in the main section of your website?   Would the navigation be different?   Does blogger add a lot of cruft onto the page?    If you are publishing the content in the main section of your site, why would you continue to use blogger at all?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if it was part of main site then headings etc would more likely push user to explore software pages but also could add pages comtaining lists of related articles making it easy to navigate. But main reason is I hope that more pages mean my software is more likely to come up in response to user searches. But blog is good for existing users who like to follow the blog and read articles as they are created, it is also easier to create pages using WYISWG blog first rather than creating html page each time.

Comment: Maybe blogger just doesn't give you enough control over the additional content on your blog pages?   Have you considered using a different blogging platform such as installing WordPress?

Comment: Bit late to change blog, but also I really dont like the architecture that wordpress uses, very flakey.

Comment: @PaulTaylor no, it isn't too late to change.  Importing blogger to WordPress is easy peasy.  And WP is hardly flakey, it powers about 30% of the web - I run a webhosting business, WP is actually quite robust..

Comment: I know its very popular but the way it uses mysql is just horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't replicate your articles, as there isn't much purpose in having them in two places. However, you could consider moving your blog to your main domain if Blogger does not give you enough flexibility.

This is really a question about whether Blogger suits your needs or not. If not, move your blog to a different provider or even just to static HTML on your main site like you mentioned. If you do, then 301 redirect the old article URLs to the new ones so that they keep most of their rank in search.

Comment: Hmm, it was meant o be a question about whther having two versions of an article can improve SEO

Comment: That part of the question is easy to answer:  it will hurt SEO.   Google will identify them as duplicate.  Google will only index one of the two. In the worst case, it will make your site look low quality and hurt the rest of your site.   See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: As Stephen said, don't have two versions of your articles that are both normal web pages. Nothing good can come of it.

Comment: So assume I used wordpress and could embed into my site rather than different subdomain I still think it would be very different to present as a series of blog articles in chronological order and as a series of landing pages where they act as the first page a potential new customer sees. So if i adjust the question somerwhat to mean that I just want to reuse the content of some blog posts to act as landing pages can I do that without incurring any duplicateion issue.

Comment: the link you provide is focussed on copying pages from other sites rather than reusing my own content.

Comment: My other issue is that the blog has posts for two different but similar products.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Since the scope of your question changed so much, the best way to get help from here on out would probably be to post a new question with the new details, then link the new question in a comment in this thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**The easy way out is to use a theme for your blogger which includes a navigation bar similar to your website.**

In such a case, people would not know the difference (generally speaking) - if users are on your website they will click on "blog tab" to navigate to blog - when users are on your blog - they can click on "website tab" to navigate to website.

Don't replicate blog content unless you are planning to retire the separate blog completely and make your website your primary blog.

Comment: Although I think the OP is probably referring to the different hostnames, rather than just the look & feel of the site - which might be reasonably seamless anyway; the OP hasn't mentioned that aspect.